# Android Access toggle button status from a custom view

Tags: android, android-custom-view, togglebutton

I have an activity `Select_episode`. This creates an adapter of `CustomListViewAdapter` which contains a toggle button.

In the `CustomListViewAdapter`, I can check the status of the toggle button in the `getView()` method.

```
final ToggleButton tgb1 = (ToggleButton) vi.findViewById(R.id.toggleButton1);
tgb1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
      if(tgb1.isChecked()){
            //do something
      }else{
            //do something
      }
}
});
```

Now rather using this `setOnClickListener` on `CustomListViewAdapter` i want to use it or check the status of this toggle button from the activity. in this case the activity is `Select_episode`

How can this be done?

Complete code of `Select_episode` : http://pastebin.com/R1mSRrqj
Complete code of `CustomListViewAdapter` : http://pastebin.com/U8Zqw924

Answer (score 1):

Implementing listeners in your Activity may not be good idea. I suggest you to implement these in `getView()` method in your `CustomListViewAdapter` class.

Then in `onClick` method you can save this `ToggleButton` value to `SharedPreferences` (with special key, that will identify `ToggleButton` from specified `ListView` position)
or try to write an method that will pass `List` with values of your all `ToggleButtons` to your `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

Create a method in your `CustomListViewAdapter` class

```
public getCheckState(int position)
{
    return items.get(position).epStatus;
}
```

and call this method in `Select_episode` to get the check status.